# C# Linq return list of records with different flags value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-8.0, c#-7.1

I have set of targetEngagementIds in engDetails object, and want to retrive targetEngagementId from object with two different filter,

1. First, to get all the TargetEngagementId without any where clause.
2. Second, to get only Ready Status TargetEngagementIds.

**How can I club these two duplicate logic as per isActiveFlag?**

```
 if (IsActiveOnly)
                {
                    if (engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.CompEngagements != null)
                    {
                        tarEngagementIds.AddRange(engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.ComponentEngagements
                                .Where(x => x.Status
                                .CaseInsensitiveEquals("Ready"))
                                .Select(x => x.TargetEngagementId)
                                .ToList());
                    }
                    if (engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.Status
                              .CaseInsensitiveEquals("Ready"))
                    {
                        tarEngagementIds.Add(engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.TargetEngagementId);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.CompEngagements != null)
                    {
                        tarEngagementIds.AddRange(engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.CompEngagements
                            .Select(x => x.TargetEngagementId)
                            .ToList());
                    }
                    targetEngagementIds.Add(engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.TargetEngagementId);
                }
```

I tried using if block to get 2 different set of data as per flag vaue. But we need to club the logic to avoid duplicate linq queries.

Comment: For the first requirement are you saying you don't want to use a `Where` cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IsActiveOnly` flag in where statement:

```cs
var ids = engDetails.TransitionDetails.InputParametersJson.ComponentEngagements
    .Where(x => x.Status.CaseInsensitiveEquals("Ready") || !IsActiveOnly)
    .Select(x => x.TargetEngagementId)
    .ToList();
```

When `IsActiveOnly` is false above query will return all ids. When `IsActiveOnly` is true it will return those where status is Ready.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitris for quick help. This is working fine as per need.